# I am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list', while trying to find the word frequency

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I am getting

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

when I am trying this piece of code:

```
from nltk import FreqDist
fd = FreqDist()
token_words = data['tweet_split'].apply(lambda tweet: tweet.split())
for i in token_words:

 fd[i] += 1
print(fd)
```

Comment: Can you show the content of data?

Comment: provide complete error message in your question

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-db8037ab8729> in <module>()
      3 token_words = data['tweet_split'].apply(lambda tweet: tweet.split())
      4 for i in token_words:
----> 5     fd[i] += 1
      6 fd

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @DeepankShekhar Instead of placing the traceback in a comment you can edit your question and add it in a pre-formatted code block

Comment: What if you try: `token_words = data['tweet_split'].apply(lambda tweet: [x for y in tweet for x in y.split()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you didn't specify exactly what `data` is, `data['tweet_split']` is likely returning a `list` of `list`s, and `FreqDist` is a probably a dictionary-like object.

So when you do `fd[i] += 1` you are indexing `fd` with a `list`, which with a dictionary or something that uses dictionaries in their implementation is not possible, because lists are not hashable.  It's possible you can convert `i` here to a `tuple` like `tuple(i)`, but it's not clear if this is exactly what you intended either.

This is because Python dicts can only be indexed with immutable objects which, by nature of being immutable, have an immutable hash value.  tuples are like lists in that they are a collection of elements, but one of the main differences is that they cannot be modified, so as long as their contents are also immutable, the tuple's hash is constant:

```
>>> t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> hash(t)
6876511439064834292
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> hash(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

`list`s could in principle be hashed, but the problem is that elements of a list can be added, removed, or modified in-place, so the hash of the list would not be constant, and thus would not be useful as a dictionary key.